# Custom configuration src jar ending up in jars folder instead of srcs when using sbt publishLocal

Tags: scala, sbt

My sbt file has an added custom configuration called "dev". I want the sources from dev configuration to end up the same way as sources from the Compile configuration, i.e., in the srcs folder of ivy local cahce when using sbt publishLocal . Is there something wrong with the authoring of the below sbt file?

```
lazy val Dev = config("dev") extend(Compile) describedAs("Dependencies required for development environments")
lazy val dpframework = project
  .in(file("datapipeline-framework"))
  .configs(Dev,Compile,Test)
  .settings(
    name := "datapipeline-framework",
    settings,
    inConfig(Dev)(Defaults.compileSettings),
    addArtifact(artifact in (Dev, packageBin), packageBin in Dev),
    addArtifact(artifact in (Dev, packageDoc), packageDoc in Dev),
    addArtifact(artifact in (Dev, packageSrc), packageSrc in Dev),
    ivyConfigurations := overrideConfigs(Dev, Test, Compile)(ivyConfigurations.value),
    defaultConfiguration := Some(Compile),
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    dependencyOverrides ++= commonDependencyOverrides,
    publishArtifact in Dev := true,
    (dependencyClasspath in Test) := (dependencyClasspath in Test).value ++ Seq(Attributed.blank((classDirectory in Dev).value))
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `Dev / packageSrc / artifact` is in the wrong Artifact type, so you can fix that as follows:

```scala
Dev / packageSrc / artifact ~= { _.withType("src") },
```

Here's the full example:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.10"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val Dev = config("dev").extend(Compile)
  .describedAs("Dependencies required for development environments")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(Dev)
  .settings(
    name := "datapipeline-framework",
    inConfig(Dev)(Defaults.compileSettings),
    addArtifact(Dev / packageBin / artifact, Dev / packageBin),
    addArtifact(Dev / packageDoc / artifact, Dev / packageDoc),
    Dev / packageDoc / artifact ~= { _.withType("doc") },
    addArtifact(Dev / packageSrc / artifact, Dev / packageSrc),
    Dev / packageSrc / artifact ~= { _.withType("src") },
    Dev / publishArtifact := true,
    Test / dependencyClasspath ++= Seq(Attributed.blank((Test / classDirectory).value))
  )
```